# To allow input text accept only numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my pluner where I have an input text which I need to make it accept only numbers.I have tried by using normal angular Js form validation but the event is not firing up .Has anyone face the similar issue,request to share your thoughts..

[Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4IA2a9EbuUlwkjqXPMt?p=preview)

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]" 
               ng-disabled="isDisabled(item.name, i)" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/"  
                             required   name="value"
                                               placeholder="Enter value">
       <span class="error pop_up" ng-show="targetForm.value.$error.pattern">Please enter only number</span>
```

Comment: `<input type="number">` ?

Comment: Have you tried this on both Chrome and Firefox? Do they act the same? Are there any errors in your web browser console? I have used Webshims for HTML5 types in the past to handle different browsers, and a jquery-mask plugin for consistent control across browsers.

Comment: I have tried on Firefox.Only the first text box inside ng-repeat i showing the error.Rest of the fields are not throwing errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onkeypress` event of textfield:

```js
 var allowOnlyNumbers=function(field){
        if (!String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).match('[0-9.]') || (field.value.match('[.]') && String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == '.'))
           event.preventDefault();
    };
```

```html
 <input onkeypress='allowOnlyNumbers(this)' type="text" ng-model="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]" 
               ng-disabled="isDisabled(item.name, i)" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/"  
                             required   name="value"
                                               placeholder="Enter value">
```